# Why do people think rapping is new and different from singing?

Tags: voice, articulation, choir, rap, choral

***Why do people think rapping is new and different from singing?***

Are Staccato (short) and Tenuto (held) the correct terms to differentiate the length of the notes and weren’t these two note speeds both considered singing?

In old chorale music (choirs),there was still instances of short notes being sung fast. There was also of course, instances of short fast notes being sung and then longer notes, within the same song.

People didn’t think of short fast notes as not being singing until recently.

Comment: "Are Staccato (short) and Tenuto (held) the correct terms to differentiate the length of the notes": no.  "Weren’t these two speeds both just considered singing?": Yes.  The difference between rap and song has very little to do (if anything) with the presence of short or long notes.

Comment: @phoog So would it  be “sixteenth notes and whole notes” or even shorter or longer notes? I asked this because I don’t think rap and singing are different and wanted to know if we differentiated them in the past. The main thing is that i’m not sure where the idea that rap is not melodic came from. So the only thing that could be truly different is the length of the notes.

Comment: Almost everyone can hear a difference between rapping and singing. They are different things. Are you intentionally implying that you cannot hear a difference between rapping and singing? Short fast notes are still considered singing. Is that what you think rapping is? Singing short fast notes? Have you ever listened to Snoop Dogg? It's rap, and it's not usually fast.

Comment: I don't think notes describe the percussive elements and emphasis involved in rap very well, it would probably be a mess with glissando everywhere ?

Comment: (Not to mention dynamics, there would be dynamics everywhere)

Comment: I think there would have to be a lot of stuff like with a throaty voice or with a silly voice or whatever under the notes as well, especially for skits, It would be interesting if someone had tried to make a system for that :-)

Comment: Sorry, even explaining why this question can’t be answered would take an answer-length comment. Ultimately, it’s a question about how certain terms are used, and it assumes several definitions that aren’t universal. The short version is: Anyone who says rapping isn’t  singing is presumably defining it as speech. (The term “rapping” after all comes from a usage meaning “conversing.”)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about definitions of terms, but uses too many terms and assumes many definitions and perhaps rests on some false premises.

Comment: @AndyBonner I understand! Its a reddit question or chat room. My apologies again lol.

Comment: "I don’t think rap and singing are different":  if you hear an unfamiliar piece of music on the radio (or elsewhere), are you unable to distinguish whether it is being rapped or sung?  Whatever the difference is, though, it has nothing to do with rhythm.  You can easily take a rap and compose a song using the same rhythm.  The primary difference is in the use of pitch.  Rap is (primarily) spoken, and the difference between speech and singing is largely a function of pitch.  Watch _The Music Man._  It has an explanation of this phenomenon along with examples of pre-rap musical speech, sung...

Comment: ..."patter" songs that in some ways approximate speech but serve as counterexamples to your apparent hypothesis that fast rhythms preclude singing, and more.  Try Rex Harrison in _My Fair Lady._  See what you think of Copland's _Lincoln Portrait._  Listen to operatic recitative from different periods -- it changed dramatically between 1600 and 1900.  There are many places where you can find gray areas between speaking and singing, but you will not find that rhythm is the critical factor in any of them.

Comment: I meant that I think a lot of rap does have intended tonality, and that from my understanding all phonations are pitched. So the only way to differentiate rap and singing would be by note length, and thats the only difference I personally perceive. This article has some good examples https://www.esm.rochester.edu/integral/34-2020/komaniecki/

Comment: If the only difference you perceive between rap and singing is note length, then I'm afraid your problem is you. People think rap is different from singing because they can hear a lot of differences that go well beyond note length.

Answer (score 5):

> Why do people think rapping is new and different from singing?

Because, well, they are.  Perhaps you meant to ask what the differences are.

> I asked this because I don’t think rap and singing are different and wanted to know if we differentiated them in the past.

I suspect that you know very well that they are different.  When you hear a piece of music for the first time, you know whether the performance includes someone rapping or singing.  It is not difficult to determine that Steve Perry *sings* "Don't Stop Believin'" and Melle Mel *raps* "White Lines."

But the focus on rhythm is misplaced.  Look at "Rapper's Delight" and the "Ketchup Song": it's the same rhythm, but one is rap and the other isn't.  Yes, rap is less likely to contain slowly declaimed text than singing, because long, drawn out, single syllables are weird and awkward in speech.  But rapid declamation does not by itself turn song into rap.  The Major General's song from *Pirates of Penzance* comes to mind.

What makes rap different from song is the use of pitch.  Singing generally has more or less well defined units of constant pitch -- notes, if you will.  These don't necessarily correspond with syllables, but often they do.  Some styles of singing don't have constant pitch, but instead the pitch slides around as it does in speech.  Still, the pitch generally begins or ends on a musically significant pitch, and may linger there a wile, in contrast to speech where the pitch isn't necessarily related to the musical accompaniment, and the variations in pitch tend to serve rhetorical ends, not musical.

So, in summary, yet another attempt to answer your question:

> Why do people think rapping is ... different from singing?

Because they hear rap as rhythmic speech rather than as singing.

The part I omitted just there is the part about whether rap is new.  Certainly rhythmic speech with musical accompaniment is an ancient art form.  In that respect, rap as a musical technique isn't new.  But rap as a musical *genre,* as a *style* of making music, also known as "hip hop," was universally recognized as an innovation of the last quarter of the 20th century.  Many aspects of it were new or given new importance, and the synthesis of the various elements was certainly innovative.  These include not just the performance technique of speaking rhythmically but also the practice of using short samples of other songs to create the rhythmic background, various stylistic elements such as African-American rhythmic patterns, and even the choice of topic.  You might reasonably (if anachronistically) describe rhythmic chanting in a 1930s big band number as "rapping," but you'd be on much thinner ice if you tried to describe the music as "rap."

Answer (score 4):

It probably has more to do with the fact that rapping is closer to rhythmic recitation than singing at a defined pitch. At least, that's why I think that rapping is different from singing. Not speed, but defined pitch as an applicable category and the fact it uses the technique of speech, which is different from the technique of singing.

I'm not convinced it's a new invention (I'm not informed, but I'd place my bet on "very old, has been with humanity since forever"), but it sure has gained popularity that it didn't have before.

Comment: Rap being with humanity forever makes sense. As far as it being more popular than it was before that is part of my question because I thought it was always a part of singing. Minus purists that think rap has to have speech as you pointed out, or a story etc, I’m pretty sure most rap actually has a defined pitch. Basically, if we strip away the language element.

Comment: @Lecifer Not sure what you mean by "language element". If you mean that rap doesn't usually include nonsense lyrics, whereas it's not that uncommon to sing "la la la", I don't think that's a defining feature. Most songs have comprehensible lyrics from beginning to end, and I don't see any reason why it should be principially impossible to use scatting in rap.

Comment: @Lecifer A lot of music classified as rap or hip-hop today does have singing in it, and a lot of rapping done on recordings does have an intentional pitch component, however rapping in its purest sense may have pitch but that doesn't mean it has tonality. Just talking always has a pitch but there isn't a musical meaning behind the pitch content of talking. With rap, there may be pitch but there isn't musical meaning to the pitch in the same way there is with singing.

Comment: @Divizna what I mean is that, if I listen to a french rapper I have no idea what he’s saying but I could still pick out his rapping as being melodic or monotonous. But many rap purists will argue that in order for it to be true rap there needs to be words and maybe even a story being told (language).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, who are “people”?

Rapping has been around since the 1970’s and there are also many examples and influences that predate it by quite a bit so I think we can safely take “new” off the table.

Rapping and singing have similarities. The main one is the fact that they both are mostly done in a rhythmic way, using specific rhythms and conforming to an established beat or tempo. The main difference is that singing incorporates hitting specific pitches with the words along with the rhythms and even though the spoken word does have pitch, rapping is done in a conversational way with little regard for specific pitches. Our voices do rise and fall in pitch to emphasize or minimize certain words or phrases as does a rappers but almost never with specific musical pitches in mind

There are instances of crossing over, where rappers will sometimes sing melodies in parts of their songs and singers will sometimes speak parts of their lyrics. This plus the fact that singers and rappers sometimes collaborate confirms there is a connection between the two.

As for long or short notes or the way they are articulated, neither rapping or singing are confined to notes of a certain length, speed or articulation. Once again, the difference is whether or not there is the intent to assign specific pitches to the words that are being spoken or sung.

Comment: "since the 1970s" is incredibly recent in music history, so, yes, it's entirely reasonable to call something that started in the 1970s "new" as compared to something that has been going on for millennia.

Comment: @phoog If you want to talk about millennia in reference to music history thats your prerogative but 50 years is a significant amount of time in musical history, especially in the last 100 to 150 years.

Comment: Well that's also true of course, but in the context of a question about an innovation that occurred within living memory we can understand "new" to mean "different from what came before." Come to think of it, that sense of "new" can be applied to innovations occurring centuries ago, such as opera around 1600.